# Regex to match strings safely

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

The following regex is meant to improve stringmatching by sanitizing the user -defined `commandPrefix` and checking for whitespace and line-endings after the specified text. `command` will generally be a single word, hence not escaped.

```
var prefix = commandPrefix.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
return text.test("/^" + prefix + command + "(?=\s|$)/");
```

Can this be improved for code readability? And am I missing any regex special characters in the sanitation?

Comment: You can remove `-` , `]` and `}` that are not special characters. Readability is a very relative idea, what is more readable: 2 lines of straight forward code or 15 lines for the same thing ( in a "readable" way)? IMO, the only thing you can do to improve the readability is to put a comment before the two lines. (assuming it could be useful for someone)

Comment: To build a pattern by concatenation, you need to use the `RegExp` constructor that can take a string as parameter. You can't write something like  `"/^" + prefix + command +...`, a RegExp instance isn't a string. As an aside Code Review is for working code.

Comment: Other thing, you can change `(?=\s|$)` to `(?!\S)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, I'll make those changes. And I was told the code worked so didn't try to check out. Would definitely do so in the future. Feel free to compile these into an answer :)

Comment: normally I use `\b` unless `(?!\S)` is exactly needed (i.e. words are delimited by whitespaces only, but not by punctuation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `/pattern/` is the literal notation of a RegExp object and not a string, `"/pattern/"` is a string and nothing more.

If you want to concatenate several strings to build your pattern and then to obtain a RegExp object, you need to use the constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp('^' + prefix + command + '(?!\\S)');
return re.test(text);
```

*(Note that when you pass a string to the RegExp constructor, you need to escape the backslashes, since to figure a literal backslash in a string you need to escape it.)*

*(`test` is a `RegExp` method, not a `String` method: [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test))*

---

About special characters: `-`, `}` and `]` are not special characters and don't need to be escaped. 
Note that `{` is read as a literal character too, but only if it isn't the start of a quantifier `{n}`, `{m,n}`, `{m,}`. Except for these special situations, you don't need to escape it when you write a pattern by hand, but here it's easier to escape it systematically instead of testing if it is or not the start of a quantifier. *(if the escape is useless, it will be ignored)*

Since you will use the RegExp constructor with a string as first parameter *(Since ECMAScript 6, this parameter can also be in literal notation)*, you no longer need to escape the delimiter `/` that is only used in the literal notation. You can remove it too:

```
var prefix = commandPrefix.replace(/[.?*+\\|{()[^$]/g, '\\$&');
```

---

About the readability, no need to make things more complicated than they are, a simple comment before the line should suffice.

Since escaping special regex characters is a basic task, and if you project to use it several times, you can build a function:

```
function regEscape(mystr) {
    return mystr.replace(/[.?*+\\|{()[^$]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

or, why not, adding it to the `String` methods:

```
String.prototype.regEscape = function() {
    return this.replace(/[.?*+\\|{()[^$]/g, '\\$&');
};

...

function ... (...) {
    ...
    var re = new RegExp('^' + commandPrefix.regEscape() + command + '(?!\\S)');
    return re.test(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want code readability, check [the escape-string-regexp solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/211369) from @CoolAJ86

---

## The Long Answer

If you're going to use the function above at least link to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/211369) in your code's documentation so that it doesn't look like crazy hard-to-test voodoo.

```
var escapeRegExp;

(function () {
  // Referring to the table here:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp
  // these characters should be escaped
  // \ ^ $ * + ? . ( ) | { } [ ]
  // These characters only have special meaning inside of brackets
  // they do not need to be escaped, but they MAY be escaped
  // without any adverse effects (to the best of my knowledge and casual testing)
  // : ! , = 
  // my test "~!@#$%^&*(){}[]`/=?+\|-_;:'\",<.>".match(/[\#]/g)

  var specials = [
        // order matters for these
          "-"
        , "["
        , "]"
        // order doesn't matter for any of these
        , "/"
        , "{"
        , "}"
        , "("
        , ")"
        , "*"
        , "+"
        , "?"
        , "."
        , "\\"
        , "^"
        , "$"
        , "|"
      ]

      // I choose to escape every character with '\'
      // even though only some strictly require it when inside of []
    , regex = RegExp('[' + specials.join('\\') + ']', 'g')
    ;

  escapeRegExp = function (str) {
    return str.replace(regex, "\\$&");
  };

  // test escapeRegExp("/path/to/res?search=this.that")
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the linked answer and the next best readability option.